# The condition of $\Pr[X_1 \in S_1| X_2 \in S_2,X_3 \in S_3 ] = \Pr[X_1 \in S_1| X_3 \in S_3 ] $

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

If $X_1,X_2$ are independent random variable, can I claim that

$$\Pr[X_1 \in S_1| X_2 \in S_2,X_3 \in S_3 ] = \Pr[X_1 \in S_1| X_3 \in S_3 ]? $$

Or else in what condition does the above equation hold?

Comment: do we know anything about $X_3$?

Comment: No, we know nothing about $X_3$.

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition is that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are conditonally independent conditionally on $X_3$, that is, $$\Pr[X_1 \in S_1,X_2 \in S_2\mid X_3 \in S_3 ] = \Pr[X_1 \in S_1\mid X_3 \in S_3 ]\cdot\Pr[X_2 \in S_2\mid X_3 \in S_3 ] $$ for every $(S_1,S_2,S_3)$.

Comment: Good answer, this is just what I want to ask in the next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be that $X_1,X_2$ are independent and have non-degenerate Bernouilli distributions.

Define $X_3=X_1+X_2$.

Then: $$\Pr(X_1=1\mid X_2=1,X_3=1)=0\neq\Pr(X_1=1\mid X_3=1)$$

---

A *sufficient* condition for the equality in your question to hold is independence of $X_1$ and $\langle X_2,X_3\rangle$.

In that case both sides equal $\Pr(X_1\in S_1)$.

This condition is *not necessary* (as is made clear in comments).

I took things too easily.

Comment: As conditional probability is also a probability, you may write something like $\Pr_1\{X_1 \in S_1|X_2 \in S_2, X_3 \in S_3\} = \Pr_1\{X_1 \in S_1|X_3 \in S_3\}$ $\iff \Pr_2\{X_1 \in S_1|X_2 \in S_2\} = \Pr_2\{X_1 \in S_1\}$, so that means $X_1, X_2$ are conditional independent given $X_3$ (assume you mean for any Borel set $S_2, S_3$ such that the marginal probability of the above events are non-zero.)

Answer (score 1):

No, let $X_1 ,X_2$ are Bernoulli r.v. with values in $\{0,1\}$, i.e. independent tosses of fair coin. Let $X_3 = X_1 + X_2$. Take $S_3 = \{0,2\}$ and $S_2 = \{1\}$, $S_1 = \{1\}$. You get
$$P(X_1\in S_1\mid X_2\in S_2 ,X_3\in S_3) = 1$$
while
$$P(X_1\in S_1\mid X_3\in S_3) = \frac{1}{2} $$